# Car has an intermittent bounce/stutter feeling in front left wheel area regardless of speed?

Tags: tires, troubleshooting, cavalier

I drive a 1997 Chevy Cavalier.

For the past little while there's been some issues with the way it's been running at all speeds. The best way to describe it is at slow speeds it feels almost like a bounce in the front-left of the car.. like if you were to drive the vehicle over very small speed bumps with a single tire, or if that tire were ovular while the rest were round (dumb comparison, but best way to explain it). The feeling does get faster at higher speeds, but seems to cap out at a certain point (it doesn't get any faster past 50km/h, for example) and will come and go at persistent speeds.

There is no noise associated with this happening. This issue seems to be most noticeable in the mornings/when everything is cold and the car hasn't been started in a day or so.

At first I thought maybe I had a wheel imbalance or a rock stuck in the tread, but I've changed out both the tires and the wheels themselves and the problem persisted. The rotors appear to be fine as well. Any possible causes for this?

I have no idea where to start looking past this point and I'm a week or two out from being able to bring my car in to a shop. Mostly just concerned about whether this is a potential vehicle-killing issue, and/or if it is unsafe to bring my car onto the highway in the meantime.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like one or both of your front shocks have worn out.
Replace them in pairs! Both fronts, both rears, you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Issue wound up being worn engine mounts fwiw!